# Square of Sums in racket/scheme

Tags: math, scheme, lisp, racket

I am writing the square of sums in racket/scheme recursively. The code sums the numbers right, but it doesn't square it right. I don't know what I am doing wrong. If I pass 10, it should be 3025.

```
(define (squareOfSums n)
 (if (= n 0)
  0
   (expt (+ n (squareOfSums (- n 1))) 2)))
```

Comment: Perhaps because all recursions also square their partial sums?

Comment: Sum everything first, then square the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do the squaring only *once*, at the end of the recursion. Currently, your code squares *at every iteration*. One way to solve this problem would be to separate the sum part into a helper procedure, and square the result of calling it. Like this:

```
(define (squareOfSums n)
  (define (sum n)
    (if (= n 0)
        0
        (+ n (sum (- n 1)))))
  (sqr (sum n)))
```

Also, did you know that there's a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) to add all natural numbers up to `n`? This is a nicer solution, with no recursion needed:

```
(define (squareOfSums n)
  (sqr (/ (* n (+ n 1)) 2)))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(squareOfSums 10)
=> 3025
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version which I think is idiomatic but which I hope no-one who knows any maths would write:

```
(define (square-of-sums n)
  (let loop ([m n] [sum 0])
    (if (> m 0)
        (loop (- m 1) (+ sum m))
        (* sum sum))))
```

Here's the version someone who knows some maths would write:

```
(define (square-of-sums n)
  (expt (/ (* n (+ n 1)) 2) 2))
```

I *wish* people would not ask homework questions with well-known closed-form solutions: it's actively encouraging people to program badly.

Answer (score 1):

If you start out with your function by writing out some examples, it will be easier to visualize how your function will work.

Here are three examples:

```
(check-expect (SquareOfSums 0)  0)
(check-expect (SquareOfSums 2)  (sqr (+ 2 1))) ;9
(check-expect (SquareOfSums 10) (sqr (+ 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1))) ;3025
```

As we can see clearly, there are two operators we are using, which should indicate that we need to use some sort of helper function to help us out.

We can start with out main function `squareOfSums`:

```
(define (squareOfSums n)
  (sqr (sum n)))
```

Now, we have to create the helper function.

The amount of times that you use the addition operator depends on the number that you use. Because of this reason, we're going to have to use natural recursion.

The use of natural recursion requires some sort of base case in order for the function to 'end' somewhere. In this case, this is the value `0`.

Now that we have identified the base case, we can create our helper function with little issue:

```
(define (sum n)
  (if (= 0 n)
      0
      (+ n (sum (sub1 n)))))
```